# Algorithm find an element in a container with a given value for one of its members

Tags: c++, boost, member-functions, boost-range, non-member-functions

Something that I have to do quite often is finding a member in a collection of elements which has an element with a given value. For example given:

```
class Person
{
   string getName() const {return mName;}
   private:
   string mName;
};

std::vector<Person> people;
```

I want to find the Person whose name is "Alice". One way to do this would be (using boost range adaptors):

```
string toFind = "Alice";
auto iterator = find(people | transformed([](Person const & p){p.getName()}) , toFind );
```

this is a lot of boilerplate for such a simple operation. Shouldn't it be possible to do something like:

```
string toFind = "Alice";
auto iterator = find(people | transformed(&Person::getName) , toFind );
```

(doesnt compile because &Person::getName is not a unary function)

Is there an easy way to get a unary function for a member?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [std::find_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) function with appropriate [lambda](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) which checks if the `getName()` value is equal to `tofind` string:

```
std::string tofind = "Alice";
auto it = std::find_if(people.begin(), people.end(), [&tofind](const Person& o) {return o.getName() == tofind; });
if (it != std::end(people)) {
    std::cout << "Contains: " << tofind << '\n';
}
else {
    std::cout << "Does not contain: " << tofind << '\n';
}
```

This would require the `getName` function to be in a `public` class scope and you should provide the appropriate constructor. Full code would be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

class Person {
public:
    Person(const std::string& name) : mName{ name } {}
    std::string getName() const { return mName; }
private:
    std::string mName;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<Person> people{ {"John"}, {"Alice"}, {"Jane"} };
    std::string tofind = "Alice";
    auto it = std::find_if(people.begin(), people.end(), [&tofind](const Person& o) {return o.getName() == tofind; });
    if (it != std::end(people)) {
        std::cout << "Contains: " << tofind << '\n';
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Does not contain: " << tofind << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Ron!, yes that is fine, but I guess it carries too much boilerplate, I would like something more compact, like:
find_if ( people ,  unary_compare(&Person::getName,alice) )

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is [`std::mem_fn`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn). It wraps a pointer to member function such that one can call it like free function, where the object on which the member function is called is passed as the first argument. In your example, you can use it like:

```
string toFind = "Alice";    
auto iterator = find(people | transformed(std::mem_fn(&Person::getName)) , toFind ); 
                                       // ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thank you @xskxzr, it was precisely what I was looking for :)